# how to load Laravel _variables.scss

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, sass, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

I have changed some values in the _variables.scss

```
 $brand-primary: #0040c0;
 $brand-info: #8eb4cb;
 $brand-success: #2ab27b;
 $brand-warning: #cbb956;
 $brand-danger: #bf5329
```

Unfortunaly my views do not reflect the changes.
How can i display the changes made?

I tried to run dump_autoload and emptied my browsers cache.

Comment: If using chrome, Did you tried running your code in incognito mode? Other browsers also have similar private modes. Try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import those variables in `app.scss` file before importing bootstrap file like so:

```
@import "variables";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Then you need to run:

```
npm run dev
```

to compile assets and assuming you use `app.css` somewhere on your site you should see the changes (obviously assuming simplest scenario - it can be much more complicated if you version your file or compile multiple files into file with other name)